# How to update query param in url in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create pagination in my web application using react-js-pagination. Pagination is showing in webpage but i want to change page param inside url according to page number like `&page=4`. I tried to use

```
this.props.history.push(`${window.location.search}&page=${pageNumber}`)
```

but this is appending `&page=4` everytime i click on pagination link. I know this wrong way to update url. How can i update only page parameter according to pageNumber in url?

```
handlePageChange = (pageNumber) => {
 this.setState({activePage: pageNumber});
 this.props.history.push(`${window.location.search}&page=${pageNumber}`)
}

<Pagination
    activePage={this.state.activePage}
    itemsCountPerPage={10}
    totalItemsCount={100}
    onChange={this.handlePageChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `location.pathname` instead of `location.search` but all the other query parameters will also be deleted.

So if you have other parameters that you need and you only want to change the `page` parameter, you can use the `URLSearchParams` javascript object which will make it easier to replace the current pagination.

So do as follows:

Create a new variable which contains the current url with all the params:

```
let currentUrlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
```

Then change the page parameter to the value you need in that variable:

```
currentUrlParams.set('page', pageNumber);
```

Now push the current url with the new params using `history.push`:

```
this.props.history.push(window.location.pathname + "?" + currentUrlParams.toString());
```

So the full code will be:

```
let currentUrlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
currentUrlParams.set('page', pageNumber);
this.props.history.push(window.location.pathname + "?" + currentUrlParams.toString());
```

Comment: this is changing url from /search?searchTerm=a to /searchTerm=a&page=2

Comment: this.props.history.push({
         pathname: '/search',
         search: `${currentUrl.toString()}`
      })

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use `pathname` instead of `search`:

```
this.props.history.push(`${window.location.pathname}&page=${pageNumber}`)
```

Comment: It dosent work this changed my url from search?searchTerm=a to search&page=2

Comment: Oh, you have other parameters! Are you using react-router?

Comment: there are other paramters in url